# Populate an entity property with api with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a Symfony entity with a property (`$user`) that should be populated from an external API (Keycloak).

This is my class:

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ShareRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Share
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    private $user;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }
    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

I also have a `UserManager` service where I can query for users in Keycloak, but I can't inject a service into an Entity, so i can't use it.

So my question is, how can I populate my `Share` entity `$user` property? I could do it on each controller, but then I would have to repeat that logic on each controller method...

I also don't want to use the "onLoad" doctrine Event as I don't want to call the keycloak API if no one is asking for the `$share->getUser()`.

Is like I would have to call the api on the `Share` class `$user` property getter, but as I said, I can't call to the `UserManager` service from my entity.

Comment: Firstly, help us understand why'd query API on each request? It's not possible for you save user and load it from database?

Comment: I would create a `PopulateShareUserService`-Service with a `populate(Share $share, $apiData): Share {}`-method. Every time you want to populate a `Share` you inject the Service into the Controller action method and use the `populate ` method e.g. `editAction(Request $request, Share $share, PopulateShareUserService $psuService) { ... $psuService->populate($share, $apiData); ... }`

Comment: @GasKa I don't want to store the users in my database to avoid duplicating information. My users database is Keycloak and I want to get the users from there. Its possible that In some future I use some cache too, but I want to keep all this logic inside the `UserManager`.

Comment: @goulashsoup this could be a solution, but in my case, I'm developing a graphql api. This means that the client can request for the `Share::$user` property or not. This is why I don't want to always populate the user, only when the client asks for it. This means that in each controller I would have to check if the client is asking for the user and populate it, and that logic is what I want to automatize.

Comment: @Carles Just put that check logic with in the Service?

Comment: Mmm this wont be a definitive solution as each query is different, and the service can't know which query "structure" is being used.